# UWP app webview get url and append params whenever there is Navigation starting

Tags: c#, uwp

I am working on a `Universal Windows Platform` Web App.where i am showing just a `Web View`. what i want is whenever there is a transition/Navigation i want to attach few parameters with URL inside `NavigationStarting`or where to attach parameter.Help appreciated

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us some code.

Comment: i have tried appending parameters `webView.Navigate(new Uri())`.but its done just once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been solved one can check if the `URL` has the specified parameters or not. and then cancel the Navigation and provides new `URL`

```
 private void OnNavigationStaring(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationStartingEventArgs args)
    {
        if(!workingProgressRing.IsActive && (workingProgressRing.Visibility != Visibility.Visible)){
            this.ShowHideUiControls(true);
        }

        if (!args.Uri.ToString().Contains("yourcheck"))
        {
            args.Cancel = true;
            string url_new = args.Uri.ToString() + "&" + myDetails[0] + "&" + myDetails[1] + "&" + myDetails[2];

            webView.Navigate(new Uri(url_new, UriKind.Absolute));
        }
        Debug.WriteLine("Navigation Starting",args.Uri.ToString());
    }
```